# Show that $\Bbb{F}^{m×n}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}^{mn}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

**Problem**-Show that $\Bbb{F}^{m×n}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}^{mn}$.

**Attempt**-Deffine a mapping $T:\Bbb{F}^{m×n}\rightarrow \Bbb{F}^{mn}$ by $T(E_{ij})=e_{n(i-1)+j}$ ,where $1≤i≤m$ and $1≤j≤n$.

I assume $E_{ij}$ ,$1≤i≤m$ and $1≤j≤n$ whose non-zero entry $(E_{ij})_{ij}=1$. It is easy to check that $E_{ij}$ form a basis for $\Bbb{F}^{m×n}$.
From here I can check that
$T$ is bijective and linear transformation.
Am I on the right track?

Also I would like to know that how it will come to mind to choose $n(i-1)+j$? I just take it as hit and trial.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension.

Comment: @Robert -I know that. What I asked? please see my problems. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track.  Alternatively, it suffices to note that any bijective function from a basis of one vector space to another uniquely extends to an isomorphism between the two spaces.

As for how this particular ordering would come to mind, the assignment $f(i,j) = n(i-1) + j$ is the result of counting the tuples $\{(i,j): 1 \leq i \leq m,\ 1 \leq j \leq n\}$ in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: Thanks a lot...