# How to show that $T$ is one-one and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $\Bbb{F}^{m×n}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}^{mn}$

**My attempt** :  I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731695/show-that-bbbfm%c3%97n-is-isomorphic-to-bbbfmn)
Here is an outline of answer

> Denote by $E_{ij}$, where $1 \le i\le m , 1\le j\le n$, the $m \times n$ matrix whose only nonzero entry is $(E_{ij})_{ij}=1$.We  have $mn$ such matrices .

> claim : we  have  $mn$ such matrices i,e they form form a basis in $\mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$

> conisder   their arbitrary linear combination  with coefiicient $a_{ij}$. we get the $m\times n$ matrix  with entries $a_{ij}$.This matrix zero if and only all coefficients are zero, so$ E_{ij}'s$  are linarly independent . On the other hand , any $m \times n$ matrix with arbitrary entries $b_{ij}$ is the linear combination of $E_{ij}$ with coefficients $ b_{ij} $ , so $E_{ij}$ span $\mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$.

> Let $e_i$ , where $1 \le i \le mn$ be standared  basis in  $\mathbb{F}^{mn}$.Then  linear operator  from $\mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$ to $ \mathbb{F}^{mn}$  that $E_{ij}$  to $e_{(i-1)n +j}$ is an isomormphism

As for how this particular ordering would come to mind, the assignment $f(i,j) = n(i-1) + j$ is the result of counting the tuples $\{(i,j): 1 \leq i \leq m,\ 1 \leq j \leq n\}$ in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

**My doubt** : I  don't know how  to count  tuples by [Lexicographical_order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

**My thinking** : Define the bijection $f$ from $\{(i,j): 1 \leq i \leq m,\ 1 \leq j \leq n\}$ to $\{1,2,3,....,mn\}$ by $f(i,j) = n(i-1) + j$

Now define a function  $T:\Bbb{F}^{m×n}\rightarrow \Bbb{F}^{mn}$

Let $A \in \mathbb{F}^{m \times  n}$ .Then  map $A$  to the $mn$-tuple  that  $A_{ij}$ in the $f(i,j)$  position

For  example  take $m=n=2$. Then $ T(\pmatrix{A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}})=(A_{11},A_{12},A_{21},A_{22})$ where $A_{11},A_{12},A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ are in $1,2,3$  and $4$ position

After that im  unable to proceed further

**My confusion** :How  to show   that   $T$ is  one-one and onto ?

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to know that $T$ is simply the row-major [vectorization mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))